# What is roaming in League of Legends?

Tags: terminology, league-of-legends

In [Elementz tier list](http://reignofelementz.com/solo-queue-tier-list) I keep reading that certain champions are very good at roaming. What is roaming? Does the term roaming come from another game or is it unique to League of Legends?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Roaming in games such as LoL is wandering around the map with the sole purpose of setting up ganks, or kills on heroes, in other lanes.

Comment: So I guess it came from DotA?

Comment: @Sadly I guess that 99% of terms come from DotA, that practically created this new game genre.

Comment: I'm sure the term was used in games before DotA, but in the specific context that it is used in League of Legends and Heroes of Newerth definitely originated in DotA. You see a lot of roaming in both HoN and DotA games at the professional level(can't speak for LoL, because I've only played a few games and never watched competitive games). In HoN and DotA, many of the classic roaming heroes are the same and often have the same qualities...high base damage, little-to-no dependency on items, and strong crowd control abilities (see a list of DotA heroes here http://www.playdota.com/learn/roam).

Comment: Things that make for good roaming in LoL are move speed (so you can get around the map faster), stealth abilities (so they don't see you coming), wall jumps/gap closers (for the element of surprise), and crowd control abilities/item effects (to stop them getting away from you).